# How to configure windows server 2012 for using SPICE?

Tags: video, virtualization, windows-server-2012, kvm

I read that the resolution of a windows server 2012 installed in a virtual machine (virt-manager,libvirt,kvm,qemu) can be improved by using [SPICE](http://www.spice-space.org).
In order to do that, I must:
1) install a specific driver (qxl) in windows server 2012,
2) configure the virtual machine for using the qxl video and the Spice display/channel.

The second point "seems" to be easy ([see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/568910/windows-server-2012-resolution-woes-with-vga)) ...

For the first point, I downloaded the driver [here](http://www.spice-space.org/download.html), by clicking http://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/qxl/qxl-0.1-21/,
Next, I extracted the content of qxl_8k2r2_x64.zip,
Finally, I tried to install the driver by the command:

```
pnputil -i-a qxl.inf
```

I received this message:

```
failed to install the driver on any of the devices on the system. no more data is available.
```

**Question**: Is my demarch correct ? Have I forgotten some stuff ?

**Note:** I also tried to install/modify the driver from the **Device Manager** by selecting the current display adapter (Microsoft Basic Display Adapter) but I received the message: device is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

No digitally signed drivers packages public available for Windows Server 2012

For those with access to rhn.redhat.com a rpm package is available with virtio-win-1.6.7. All drivers are signed by Redhat so they install without any problems. The qxl.sys driver must be installed from the drivers folder using pnputil -i -a qxl.inf from a cmd terminal. Remember this cmd terminal must be run as root.

Comment: you copied the text on Proxmox ! did you test yourself ?

Comment: and qxl.sys doesn't exist in this package !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is how you installed the driver, because I installed the driver the same way. The problem is the driver itself. There is another project on github for a driver with support for Windows 8 and Windows 2012. I tryed that one and it works perfectly well for me on Windows 2012 Server!

Here is the link to the project: https://github.com/vrozenfe/qxl-dod

On the page you can find a link to binaries as well.